# What factors should I consider when setting a Linguistic Corpus price?

Tags: computational-linguistics, nlp, corpora

What are the factors that must be considered when setting a linguistic corpus price?

Is there any standard model or something else I should follow?

Comment: What do you mean by setting up a price? If you're asking us how much you should charge, I don't think this is the right place to ask that. :)

Comment: I've create one linguistic corpus with special characteristics and want to set a price for that to sale it ,so what is the factors for pricing linguistic corpus?

Comment: Well, it might help if you included those characteristics in your question. As is, it's pretty vague, so including those details would be helpful for others that want to answer (this is true in general). However, I'm not sure this is a Linguistics question even if it concerns corpora...

Comment: I agree the question is extremely vague, but I think it's on topic. If we allow questions on how to compile corpora or what corpus to choose for a certain research question then questions on pricing also seem worthwhile.

Comment: @robert I disagree, i don't think monetisation of resources - even linguistic resources - is an appropriate topic for this SE.

Comment: Since this is not a question about linguistics, I think that this question should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any standard models but *size*, *source(s)*, *quality*, *fitness for purpose*, *language(s)* and *copyright vettedness/copyright restrictions* seems like relevant factors. Big size (a copy of the internet) isn't necessarily an asset if what the buyer needs is a domain-specific high quality corpus. There are many corpora already for English, fewer for other languages, but fewer are studying other languages so the market is smaller and they can pay less.

Corpora with too strict licensing can be worthless because you can't use the data for what you need to use it for or there are restrictions on publishing methods etc. As to vettedness: not good to have to scrap research because the seller didn't have the right to sell the raw data in the first place... There was a lot of copyright angst when I dipped my toes into corpus linguistics years ago.

Advice: Be a salesman, pose as a buyer to figure out what the competition is doing :)